# how to put fix password in hbase by another sh?

Tags: bash, cygwin, hbase, sh

The hbase is installing in windows base on Cygwin
i use an sh to run the start-hbase.sh, it works, but still require for the password, is there any way can put the fix password in?
Thank you.

Comment: did anyone know about how to using sh to go directly to the path that to start the hbase?
For example:
the path for starting hbase is in hbase/bin how to use a sh file to access to this directory directly?

Comment: the path problem is solve left the password, when batch file crossing to cygwin it need an password to enter into cygwin mode.
do anyone know how to make the password fix ?